# virtual url in the ui router parameter in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an application with ui-router routing system, I make a url like this

```
.state( 'pulse.detail',{
            abstract: true,
            url:"/:stockId/:stockTitle",

            templateUrl: "views/stockAnalaysis/stockAnalysisExp.html",

              resolve:{
                        stockId: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams,stockId){
                        return $stateParams.stockId;
                                }],
                        namad: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams,namad){
                        return $stateParams.namad;
                                }]
                    }

        })
```

this rout export this url : `index.html/#/12/something`
when i enter url like this : `index.html/#/12/some`
it redirects to 404 page
how can in make force to  this action to have same effect on  this url `index.html/#/12/something` and this `index.html/#/12/some` or `index.html/#/12/*` and show specific page?

Comment: abstract states are only accessible through a child state, create a state that is the child of `pulse.detail`

Comment: i consider all of that states